# Can I use my PSOne memory card saves on digital copies downloaded from PSN?

Tags: psn, psone-classics

I was wondering if is it possible to use my original PSOne saved games (in particular, from Final Fantasy VII, VIII, IX and Tactics) on the digital games downloaded from the PlayStation Store. Obviously after transfering these save files via the PS3 Memory Card adapter.

Comment: That's a good question. I'll see if I can try it at home. I'd have to buy one of the games on PSN though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can. I've done it with Final Fantasy VII and the Spyro games- they all worked perfectly.

Comment: Well that is a relief... thanks to you we know that it works on FF7 and Spyro ... BUT ... does it means it WILL work on the other FF?

Comment: It will work on all games.

Comment: There you go then! ... Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: The only caveat to this is that Pocket Station saves won't function as Pocket Station data.